# write on FTP file without overwrite previous text ftplib python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftp-client, ftplib

I'm trying to write on hosted file from python, so I chose to use ftplib module.
So far i got this code

```
from ftplib import FTP
import io
ftp = FTP('ftp.myhostname.com')
ftp.login('myusername','mypass')
#ftp.retrlines('LIST')
bio = io.BytesIO(b'randomtext')
ftp.storbinary('STOR test.php', bio)
#ftp.retrbinary('RETR /test.php', "test", wb)
input()
```

but it overwrites the previous text.

Comment: Does that imply that you want to append the new contents to an end of an existing file? See [Append data to file on FTP server in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30103662/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I got this error `ftplib.error_temp: 451 Append/Restart not permitted, try again` and I dont want to append text file, I want to append just text

Comment: Then you server does not support appending.